# materialdesifntoolkit wpf make popupbox open even user clicks outside of popupbox

Tags: wpf, material-design-in-xaml

Is there anyway to make the popupbox stays open even the user clicks outside of the popup in MaterialDesginToolkit WPF. currently the popupbox opens but it closes automatically when user clicks outside of the popupbox

Comment: Only guessing, but I would assume you need to be looking at the popupbox loses focus event, hope that helps

Comment: Show us the code that you wrote

Answer (score 1):

For future reference:

```
<materialDesign:PopupBox StaysOpen="True"></materialDesign:PopupBox>
```